# PayPal Guest Checkout - Change country based on provided country code

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there any way to change the country by passing the country code to PayPal rest-api-sdk-php.
I need to auto-fill the country based on the passing country when opening this popup.

Tried to change with payer info like this,

```
$country_code = $userAddress->country // this will return US,NZ,AU like country code based on selected user
$payer->setPayerInfo(new PayerInfo(array('email' => $user->email,'country_code'=>$country_code)));
```

Already fixed address details and it is working all other fields except country.

```
    $shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();
    $shipping_address->setCity($userAddress->city);
    $shipping_address->setCountryCode($userAddress->country);
    $shipping_address->setPostalCode($userAddress->postcode);
    $shipping_address->setLine1($userAddress->address);
    $shipping_address->setLine2($userAddress->address_2);
    $shipping_address->setState($userAddress->state);
    $shipping_address->setPhone($userAddress->phone);
    $shipping_address->setRecipientName($user->fullName());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal-PHP-SDK for v1/payments is deprecated, so first of all you shouldn't be using that.  Instead, there is a v2/orders Checkout-PHP-SDK as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

You are perhaps looking for the `locale` parameter, which defaults from the language set in the user's browser, e.g. topmost in the language **dropdown** of `chrome://settings/languages`.  Depending on how you are invoking the popup, setting a locale at the API level may have no effect.